# I can't enable SimpleTest due to open_basedir restriction being in force

Tags: 7, testing

I can't enable SimpleTest due to an open_basedir restriction being in force for my Drupal7 installaton which resides on a Linux server running PHP 5.2.12. I found the directive under my PHP.INI file but it is already commented out there.

When I try to enable SimpleTest in my Modules config, I see the following error:

"The testing framework requires the PHP open_basedir restriction to be disabled. Check your webserver configuration or contact your web host. (Currently using PHP open_basedir restriction Enabled)"

What can I do to overcome this? A search on the web so far has not been overly helpful.

Comment: Be sure you are using the right php.ini file; on some systems, there is more than a php.ini file. Check with `phpinfo()` which file is used.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried using "find / -name php.ini" which listed 4 occurrences of php.ini, one being for Plesk which I was expecting. I had a look through all of them and in all cases, open_basedir was commented out. So I don't understand why it thinks it's enabled?

Comment: do like i said and use a "blank" phpinfo.php file with phpinfo(); function call , you will see which php.ini is used and if open_basedir is enabled or not